# dbDelta only creates the last table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wpdb, dbdelta

I'm using following install function with dbDelta as referring to the codex, articles on SO I watched out for the typical problems with e.g. one space instead of two spaced at the PRIMARY KEY ...

```
function myplugin_install(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "vehicles";       

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name 
    (
        id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        description         VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );  
    ";

    $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name1 
    (
        ...
    )";

    $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_nameX 
    (
        id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        art_alarmierung     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
echo $wpdb->last_error;

}
```

dbDelata only stores the last `$sql` variable. And echo `$wpdb->last_error;` don't show any errors?
Where is my failure?

BR;
mybecks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `dbDelta` for each SQL statement seperately:

```
function myplugin_install(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "vehicles";       
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name 
    (
        id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        description         VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );  
    ";
    dbDelta($sql);

    $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name1 
    (
        ...
    )";
    dbDelta($sql2);

    $sql3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_nameX 
    (
        id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        art_alarmierung     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

    dbDelta($sql3);

}
```

Comment: works like charm. I tried all .. creating an array with sql expression, but won't work too. And don't get this easy solution in my mind :)

Answer (score 9):

For those trying to understand how some plugins, like WooCommerce, are able to do that without calling `dbDelta` for every table, the reason is the `IF NOT EXISTS`  part of query. The `dbDelta` function creates an index based on what comes after `CREATE TABLE`, so it ends up guessing that all queries create the same table.

If you got here, try to use just `CREATE TABLE tablename` and it will work :)

Comment: This is a good explanation. I can't tell from the Codex, but does DB delta try to create a table even if one exists and then throws an error?

Comment: It tries to figure out what would be the necessary SQL query to alter that table and make it like the current CREATE TABLE statement. Give a look at lines ~2414 here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/